# What do I call a date by which document have force?

Tags: formality, dates

I am writing technical documentation and I can guarantee, that it is in up-to-date status at the date I write it (or update it). How do I call this date in one or two words?

Comment: Denis Kulagin, the "how to call" and "how do I call" wordings are incorrect in English. You should replace the *how* with *what*. You would benefit from reading the discussion at this link http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english

Comment: @Tristan_r Many thanks for your comment! I am constantly trying to improve my English, but there is obviously room to grow!

Comment: Denis Kulagin, you also need to edit the last line of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Latest revision: 2014-05-08."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to report that the status is what was valid at a particular date (but may have changed later): "Status/Accurate as at 30 February 2014"

If a regulation and it is to take force on a specific date (usually implies from that date onwards): "In force (as) from/Effective on 30 February 2014"

Answer (score 1):

The actual date could be the *last updated date* but it would also be common to use the term *current version* or *current at 'your date'*