# How to call an email address for email-based submission to a blogging site?

Tags: phrase-requests, email

Many online sites generate a customized address for you like CAeporFsks2373454-submission@myblogging.com. You may write an email to that address and what you write in the body of that email gets published or entered in a database.

Some sites like Trello refer to it as "your email" but it is not 'your' email account (e.g. From: amanda23@hotmail.com) but a dummy electronic mail address you are supposed to write to (To: CAeporFsks2373454-submission@myblogging.com).

How to call an email address for submission?

Comment: It's a temporary address/ transient address. Certainly not 'your' account.

Comment: This Q is better asked on SO.

Comment: user78270, the "how to call" wording is incorrect in English. You should replace the *how* with *what*. You would benefit from reading the discussion at this link http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english

Comment: naming of terms is off topic at ELU.

Answer (score 1):

I would call that an *upload email address* (currently, the term yields nearly 300,000 Google hits at my time/location), or a *submission email address* (circa 2,200,000 hits).

Answer (score -2):

I would like to call that as 'publishing' email address.

Comment: That would probably not be understood without the proper context.