# identifying a specific fallacious argument

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, rhetoric

What do you call redefining your opponent's argument to better suit your own prejudice ?

For instance, declaring that those who 'think' that a film will not be successful in Europe actually 'wish'  so.

Comment: This is a "framing the argument" issue rather than a "logical fallacy" (that is, "faulty reasoning") issue. It doesn't make the tactic any less deceptive, but I don't think that "logical fallacy" is an appropriate category name for what you're talking about. (Then again, perhaps I'm guilty of the very redefining "fallacy" that you have in mind.)

Comment: Hi, I'm just going through posts which have "How do you call....?" in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing yours to *“What do you call redefining ....?”* Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for "straw man"?

*A straw man is a common type of argument and is an informal fallacy based on the misrepresentation of an opponent's argument. To be successful, a straw man argument requires that the audience be ignorant or uninformed of the original argument.*

*The so-called typical "attacking a straw man" argument creates the illusion of having completely refuted or defeated an opponent's proposition by covertly replacing it with a different proposition (i.e., "stand up a straw man") and then to refute or defeat that false argument ("knock down a straw man") instead of the original proposition.*

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man)

Answer (score -1):

The technical term for the fallacy of negating an argument by discrediting the person making it is: *argumentum ad hominem*

Comment: True, but the OP is asking about the distortion of an *argument*, not the *interlocutor's character* or *reputation*.

Comment: @erikkowal True, but when a question get some downvotes then any answer is good.

Answer (score -1):

Special pleading, I believe, is what this is called. You can look it up if you are interested in more detail.

Comment: Can you supply references to support your statement?

Comment: @Ornello Your comment has been deleted. Do not respond to reasonable requests with rudeness. Rudeness is not tolerated.