# Stele on the road while approaching a town

Tags: vocabulary

How would you call a stele on the road at the city entry like this?

[image: A Stele]

Comment: Hi, every so often I go through posts which have "How do you call....?" or "How are ______ called?"  in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing your title to *“**What** would you call a stele...?”* Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **Welcome** (city) **sign**, as stated in [Wikipedia Wiki](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welcome_sign):

> - A welcome sign (or gateway sign) is a road sign at the border of a region that introduces or welcomes visitors to the region.[1](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welcome_sign) Examples of welcome signs can be found near political borders, such as when entering a state, province, county, city, or town, and they are increasingly found in neighborhoods and private communities.

The Welcome to Fabulous Las Vegas sign:

> - is a Las Vegas landmark funded in May 1959 and erected soon after by Western Neon. The sign was designed by Betty Willis at the request of Ted Rogich, a local salesman, who sold it to Clark County, Nevada.

[image]

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

These are generically called *Monument signs*
[Here's a Google image search for "monument signs"](http://www.google.com.my/search?q=monument+sign&tbm=isch)

And I would refer to a Monument sign at the border of a city to be a [*city monument sign*](http://www.google.com.my/search?q=city+monument+sign&tbm=isch)