# What would boating be otherwise called?

Tags: word-choice

Let's suppose I am going to make a trip down the river on a boat which will last for a few days like that in *Three Men in a Boat* book. What would you call this type of activity? I have been suggested *rafting*, but as far as I know it means rather going down quite rough and fast water, as distinct from my case - calm and slow river.

Comment: As Charon suggests, "rowing", "sailing", "rafting", et al are terms for specific kinds of "boating".  ("Rafting" means riding on a raft.  The roughness of the ride has little to do with it.)  None of the terms would be appropriate for a trip in a standard power boat.  "Cruse" is a term that can fit, where the ride is essentially a pleasure ride of some length (hours or days), vs one focused on sailing, fishing, water skiing, etc.

Comment: Hi, every so often I go through posts which have "How do you call....?" or "How are ______ called?"  in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing your question to *“**What** would you call this type ....?”* Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how the boat was propelled, you could say ***rowing*** or ***sailing***.

Alternatively, you could say you were going on a ***cruise***.

I must say however, that ***boating*** is a very apt description for such an activity.

Answer (score 0):

The roughness of the ride has little to do with it.  None of the terms would be appropriate for a trip in a standard power boat. "Cruise" is a term that can fit, where the ride is essentially a pleasure ride of some length (hours or days), vs. one focused on sailing, fishing, water skiing, etc.