# What do you call someone who spends his time enjoying himself, especially one who behaves irresponsibly

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a rich man who spends his time enjoying himself, especially one who behaves irresponsibly but is not a playboy? Someone without being sexually promiscuous yet going to social events, games and so on?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63037/discussion-on-question-by-ipea-sky-rock-how-do-you-call-a-spends-his-time-enjoyi).

Comment: [What do you call....?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english?noredirect=1&lq=1) is the correct way of asking the name of something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A **sybarite** or **epicure** (only if talking about food/wine on this one) or **bon vivant**. You could use **hedonism** but sometimes people will use that word to include things like sexual activities (however the definition has nothing to do with that - it's just a synonym of sybarite). – Kace36
>
> If you want it to mean irresponsible use of money as well then use a word like: **thriftless**, **prodigal**, **ruinous**, **imprudent**, etc... – Kace36
>
> **Socialite** fits too I think. merriam-webster.com/dictionary/socialite – Max Williams

---

#### Definitions:

**Sybarite**:

> a person who is self-indulgent in their fondness for sensuous luxury.

**Epicure**:

> a person who takes particular pleasure in fine food and drink.

**Bon vivant**:

> a person who devotes themselves to a sociable and luxurious lifestyle.

**Hedonism**:

> the pursuit of pleasure; sensual self-indulgence.

**Thriftless**:

> (of a person or their behaviour) spending money in an extravagant and wasteful way.

**Prodigal**:

> spending money or using resources freely and recklessly; wastefully extravagant.

**Ruinous**:

> costing far more than can be afforded.

(Also has 'disastrous or destructive' meaning)

**Imprudent**:

> not showing care for the consequences of an action; rash.

**Socialite**:

> a person who is well known in fashionable society and is fond of social activities and entertainment.

All definitions from ODO.

Comment: If someone wants to put in links, please do!